# MYOB ODBC - Visual Studio 2010 Professional tables not shown

Tags: visual-studio-2010, odbc

I am trying to create an application that talks with company datafile (read and write access.

I was advised that ODBC is not supported on Windows 8/10 so I setup an environment with Windows 2008 server and Visual Studio 2010 professional.

What I did:

-I setup in virtual environment a Windows 2008 server R2 Standard

-Installed Myob AccountRight Premiere 19

-Created a new company, activated, make sure my serial has ODBC enabled and “Enable company file online” Talked with MYOB support to make sure I have ODBC access enabled on my serial

-Created a DSN (using ODBC 32 utility) - my MYOB key is in

-Tested ODBC connection using ODBC TestConnection utilility from C:\MYOBODBCAU10\bin\iwinnt folder-> All good

-In Visual Studio 2010 professional created a Database connection, tested.-> All good

-New connection is listed in Server explorer,  when I click on it, it expands and I see: Tables, Views, Procedures but when I click to expand "Tables"  there is nothing. If I try to run a query , nothing to query.

Answer (score 1):

An MYOB v19 company file is actually an ISAM database. The ODBC driver does not expose the database directly, but provides a set of services that provide access to it (these are actually mediated by the MYOB executable import/export functionality). Accordingly, some schema discovery operations that Visual Studio requires simply don't work. You will have to execute SQL text through an ADO.NET OdbcConnection object. Grab a copy of the document here to get you started: http://developer.myob.com/resources/odbc-driver/

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation. Visual Basic 6 on Windows 2003 server is the last environment where you can "see myob tables listed"